# How do I reference a function in a controller NOT residing in the Controllers catalog?

Tags: c#, angularjs, model-view-controller

I have a piece of script like this:

```
return $http.get('/Home/GetPersons');
```

As long as the function GetPersons resides in the HomeController in Controllers, all is fine and dandy, but I need to move it to a Controller that will not be in the Controllers-directory but rather in [Project]/API/somethingController so how would I reference that in my code?

Comment: refer it as `something/GetPersons`

Comment: Does not work. Bear in mind, it's NOT under the default Controllers-folder.

Comment: You would probably need to create a different route for this new structure. But first, I would really try to understand why you need such thing.

Comment: Because we're building a back end part of a site and all the API's are in a separate folder. Since it's not my place to rearrange the structure I have to find a way to work with the structure provided...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

asuming you use asp.net web api you can ***add new route*** like this

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        // Web API routes
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional });
    }
```

and then in angular you can query you `ProductsDataController` it like

```
$http.get('api/ProductsData/MyControllerAction');
```

P.S. in asp.net there is naming convention - to call `EntitiesController` you should refer to it as `Entities` in url

Comment: I just double checked the route... They had left out the "{action}" part... I proceeded to add it et voila! It works! Thanks!

Comment: if you use REST you can avoid using  {id} in route mask. but i eventually had to use it. so yes, if you declare {id} in route you should add action name to your query URL. i updated the answer, so may be it's worth to mark it as helpful now